# How to random java string array , that each array will be true random?

Tags: java, arrays

i have java string array which looks like this :

```
String [] cards = {"c1","c2","c3", , , , , , ,, , "c45"};
```

so i have there 45 elements , now i like to rendom them each time 
so it will be :

```
int[] cards2  = Arrays.copyOf(cards , cards .length);
random(cards2);
```

how should be the random function look like ?

Comment: What do you mean by true random?

Comment: so if i run say 10 + random function on the same orderd array it will never be the same result

Comment: it's not true random it's call pseudo random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));
```

Comment: is it good random function , if i run it 10 times each time it will be random ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you want to copy to a new array.

```
public String[] randome(String[] arr) {
   Random rgen = new Random();

   String[] randArray = new String[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, randArray, 0, arr.length);

   for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
    int randIn = rgen.nextInt(randArray.length);
    String temp = randArray[i];
    randArray[i] = randArray[randIn];
    randArray[randIn] = temp;
    }

    return randArray;
 }
```